# How to concatenate date value with a string?

Tags: google-sheets, concatenate

I need to create the following value:

```
// "ABC" + current date + some random number
ABC20160405123
```

I do as follows:

```
=CONCATENATE("ABC", NOW(), 123);
```

But instead of getting expected value I get something weird in date segment:

```
ABC42465.889227419123
```

How can I get pure date in `concatenate()`?

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the date value to a string of the form yyyymmdd. The [`text`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?hl=en) formula does this:

```
=text(today(), "yyyymmdd")
```

(It's better to use `today()` instead of `now()` when you want the date only.)

The entire formula would be

```
=concatenate("ABC", text(today(), "yyyymmdd"), 123)
```

or, more concisely,

```
="ABC" & text(today(), "yyyymmdd") & 123
```

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate the concatenate function altogether and join them using the `&` and transforming the data to a text format:

```
="ABC"&text(TODAY(),"yymmdd")&"123"
```